# Change all records at once. Update one field with same input mysql

Tags: mysql, rows, multiple-columns

I am trying to change all input for one field of all records though can't figure it out.  Any help is much appreciated.

I was trying to change them by using:

```
SELECT * FROM `users` SET 'password'='NewPassword';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE is the proper command for changing values in MySQL - example:

```
UPDATE `users` set password='new_password_string' where password is not null
```

Comment: I tried using UPDATE `users` SET 'password' = '5560bafaba4802ee6779305092db67a2'; but it didn't work either.  Could you let me know how I can accomplish this using UPDATE.

Comment: Could you please tell us what is the error which you are getting when you are running the above command?

Comment: I tried using        

UPDATE `users` SET 'password' = '5560bafaba4802ee6779305092db67a2' WHERE 'password' IS NOT NULL;

But that gave a syntax error also.

Comment: Had quotes around users and password in two places....took them out and used 

UPDATE users SET password = '5560bafaba4802ee6779305092db67a2' WHERE password IS NOT NULL;

Worked as need.  Always something simple.  Thank you so much for your response :-)

Answer (score 0):

try looking up the update statement

Answer (score 0):

You need an `UPDATE` statement, not a `SELECT` statement to update rows in your table. (Hence why it's called update.) Also, you use backticks or nothing around the column name, not single quotes.

```
UPDATE `users` SET `password`='NewPassword';
```

That being said, storing passwords in plaintext as you appear to be doing is **incredibly** insecure. Please make sure you implement a proper password hashing system.

Comment: I just used NewPassword as an example. I am using MD5 encryption to store passwords.  Good tip though :)

Comment: @JustinValinski Glad to see that you are being mindful of security. Just to mention though, MD5 is not designed for password storage because it is indended to be efficent which is good for using to verify file integrity, but bad for stopping bruteforce attacks on passwords. Something like php's `crypt()` or the equivalent is recommended instead.

Comment: Had quotes around users and password in two places....took them out and used 

UPDATE users SET password = '5560bafaba4802ee6779305092db67a2' WHERE password IS NOT NULL;

Worked as need.  Always something simple.  Thank you so much for your response :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `UPDATE` command (http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

```
UPDATE 'users' SET 'password' = 'NewPassword';
```